# .blur() not working for label

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to call [webmethod] on blur of label. But my problem is:

```
$('#clarity_lbl').on('blur', function () {
        alert("hi");
});
```

or

```
$('#clarity_lbl').blur(function () {
         alert("hi");
});
```

or

```
$('#clarity_lbl').bind('blur', function () {
        alert("hi");
});
```

is not working. `#clarity_lbl` is id of my label.

Comment: can you http://jsfiddle.net it so that we can have a look to exact problem

Comment: might be that your target element is not loaded when the script is executed.. try using event delegation - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: My target element is static not dynamic. It is also display while loading page.

Comment: try `$(document).on('blur', '#clarity_lbl', function () {})`

Comment: I tried it. But still not working..

Comment: Please add your aspx code!

Answer (score 0):

As Arun mentioned, your problem is likely that the element you are targeting does not yet exist on the page when you attempt to bind your handler to it.

To fix this, you can use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). Instead of binding to the element directly (because it doesn't exist yet), you bind to another element in it's hierarchy that **is present** on page load delegating the listener to it. In the delegation, you pass in the `id` or `class` of the target element. So this parent element will then listen for clicks on elements matching your selector within it's children and call your function if it hears one.

You can always delegate to `$(document)` but best practice is to delegate to an element as close to the dynamically added target element as possible.

```js
$("#container").on("blur","#clarity_lbl", function(event, ui) {
    alert("hi");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <input type="text" id="clarity_lbl" value="click then click away" size="100"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bro... It works properly for textbox, but i want this for label only. what should i do??

Comment: For a label like: `<label for="male">Male</label>` ? If so, how is the label getting `focus` in the first place? Is it `contentEditable="true"` or something? Can you better describe what you are trying to do? Maybe this is an X Y problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: My label is for custom drop down list. So I want to call web service on its blur event. Based on label's value I have to do some task. my label is like: 
<div class="span_label" id="clarity_lbl_div">
       <label id="clarity_lbl">FL</label></div>

Comment: Is this custom as in self written or is it a library you're using for the dropdown?

Comment: Dropdown contains list items from sql database.

Comment: What happens when the user clicks one of the labels?

Comment: Thanks bro... I got it. I found one alternate of label. Now its working.